# How do I define a confidence band for a custom (nonlinear) function?

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I am struggling to calculate / define confidence bands to use with a custom function that I must fit to my data. I have seen plenty of examples for standard models (linear regression, log functions, etc.). However, calculating the intervals to add bands to my custom function is proving tricky. Below I have the data and my function (working in R):

```
data <- matrix(c(0.08, 0.1, 0.12, 0.13, 0.49, 0.11, 0.12, 0.15, 
                 0.22, 0.47, 7, 8, 9, 21, 30, 3, 8, 13, 15, 17 ), ncol=2)
mycurve <- function(x){ a + (b*log(x)) }
a    <- 31
b    <-  9
data <- as.data.frame(data) # So that ggplot can use it
ggplot(data, aes(V1,V2)) + geom_point() + stat_function(fun=mycurve, color="red")
```

And the result is:

[image]

The red curve is the custom function that I *must* use for this dataset. This is one example, but I have a few more datasets and must fit a different function to to each dataset. So I'm looking for an approach for calculating confidence bands that I can use for any function.

I have spent quite a while on this, but haven't yet found a "generic" solution.

Comment: 1. I don't see any fitting going on there; this makes it a bit hard to guess what the situation actually is -- how are the coefficients obtained? 2. Are you seeking a pointwise interval or is the interval a simultaneous one for the whole curve in the range of the data?

Comment: @Glen_b Please see my explanation in response to Dalton's comment below. I'm looking to draw the interval for the whole curve i.e. confidence bands rather than just intervals around each point.

Comment: You misunderstand -- you will get bands either way. The distinction refers to how the proportion falling in the bands is computed. "Pointwise" means that at each point there's a CI calculation (this is the more common one); the CIs taken together give a smooth curve. .

Comment: @Glen_b are "pointwise" more common? When I think confidence band, I think a continuous curve within the range of the observed $x$. And by each point, do you mean an estimate of the mean $y$ at each observed $x$ value?  I assume you do, but it might not be clear to other readers.

Comment: @DaltonHance See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_and_prediction_bands#Pointwise_and_simultaneous_confidence_bands), which has [this diagram](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/01/Regression_confidence_band.svg/325px-Regression_confidence_band.svg.png) of the distinction in regression. As you see, both are "continuous bands", but the pointwise interval is narrower.

Comment: Just goes to show you can get  graduate degree in Statistics and not be exposed to some language. So the difference is a multiple comparisons adjustment? If you really think multiple comparison is a big deal (I'm not convinced for every circumstance) then "simultaneous" makes sense for something with factorial nature (e.g. old school ANOVA, ANCOVA), but I fail to see how this adjustment makes sense for a regression with two coefficient. With more data you would wind up with a worse confidence interval because of more multiple comparisons!

Answer (score 3):

As Glen_b pointed out, you aren't actually fitting a relationship here. You're simply plotting a curve. There is no obvious relationship between this curve and the data.

However, if what you want to do is fit a curve that follows the form you've given: $y = a+b*\mathrm{log}(x)$, where $x$ and $y$ are data and you want to find $a$ and $b$ then I can answer your question. A generic solution to the problem of fitting a non-linear relationship between some predictor, $x$, and some predicted value $y$ is to use [non-linear least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_least_squares). This carries some of the usual assumptions of linear regression, that is that the $x$ values are measured without error and that the variance of the residuals of the relationship are i.i.d. The computation of the relationship is no where near as easy as for simple linear regression, but luckily we have computers for that.

This is implemented in R by the `nls` function. You will need to provide starting values for the coeffiecients. Typically this is done by linearizing the relationship (that is finding a transformation for $y$ such that the relationship on the RHS is linear, then fitting a linear regression and using those estimates as starting values.

To get confidence bands on the relationship, you will need to use an error propagating function. An [implementation](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/propagate/docs/predictNLS) of that for `nls` in R is available in the `propagate` package in the function `predictNLS`.

EDIT: Working example and a note that the fit curve you gave does not match the point estimate of the best fit.

```
library(propagate)
library(ggplot2)

DirkSnyman <- data.frame(x = c(0.08, 0.1, 0.12, 0.13, 0.49, 
                 0.11, 0.12, 0.15, 0.22, 0.47), 
            y = c(7, 8, 9, 21, 30, 
                  3, 8, 13, 15, 17))

DS.fit <- nls(y ~ a+b*log(x), data = DirkSnyman, start = list(a = 31, b = 9))

preds <- data.frame(x = seq(0.05, 0.5, 0.01))
prop <- predictNLS(DS.fit, newdata = preds)

preds$mean <- prop$summary[,2]
preds$lcl <- prop$summary[,5]
preds$ucl <- prop$summary[,6]

mycurve <- function(x){ a + (b*log(x)) }
a    <- 31
b    <-  9


ggplot(DirkSnyman, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + 
  stat_function(fun=mycurve, color="red") + 
  geom_line(data = preds, aes(x = x, y = mean), color= "blue") +
  geom_ribbon(data = preds, 
              aes(x = x, y = mean, ymin = lcl, ymax = ucl), 
              color= "blue", alpha = .5)
```

[image]

Comment: I fitted the original curve in TableCurve software. So a and b are the estimated parameters from that process. TableCurve gave the equation as y=a+blnx with a=31.02 (s.e.= 5.4) and b=9.9 (s.e.=2.8). So I used the equation and parameter values for drawing my graphs in R as posted above.

Comment: Why not just do the whole process in R? `nls` gives the same answer, and you can do everything in one environment and achieve your confidence bands.

Comment: your code was great for `log` and `exp` functions, but I struggled with functions like `y ~ a*sinpi(2*x/c+b)` -- I added an edit to your answer with the new data, function and associated hassles.